# REST API SharePoint 2013 Document Upload

Tags: 2013, document-library, rest, file-upload

I'm working an on prem SharePoint site which I want to upload a document to it from a website. I can open up the IP from the site to allow for traffic.  The site is built in PHP so I would like to use the REST API.  My concern is that I've only seen REST API for apps in SharePoint.  Does anyone have a good example of using REST API in php or JavaScript?  Does this have to be done with a .NET library?

Comment: REST is an **endpoint** so it doesn't matter if you call it from SP, PHP, a browser REST plugin or the moon, the endpoint is always the same. You do need to allow external sites to access the endpoint.